# Adobe Air native extension for Google Tag Manager

Tags: air, adobe, google-tag-manager

If the iOS app is developed in Adobe Air environment, we want to implement Google Tag Manager (not Google Analytics). Is there any existing native extension out there? Or we have to create custom ANE for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any extensions. Out of curiosity what use case are trying to solve with GTM in Adobe Air?

Comment: @activescott: thanks for replying! we want to implement GTM for GA, adding tags and other third-party tracking. is there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google (really Adobe) provides Google Analytics for Flash](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro?csw=1), which should work with Air. Google does not provide a version of Google Tag Manager optimized for Flash/Air.

However, if you are just interested in third-party tracking/analytics tools, consider Segment.io which, although they don't provide an Air-specific library, they do provide a supported REST API that could be used from from Air. Segment also has a notable presence on GitHub, so it might be worthwhile to publish your Adobe Air client on GitHub and see if they would help foster it with the Segment community on GitHub.